# Where is the theme function in drupal?

Tags: drupal

I´m trying to follow this steps:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2025313

This is my first day in drupal and I have a problem in the first step =(

This:

Identify the file your theme function came from (theme.inc? a core/modules/color/?)

How I can find this "theme function"? I was looking for into a files of the project but I cand find this....

I get this project from other person and I can´t ask him "ey, where is the theme function?" Maybe I have wrong concepts and I don´t know where search...

Can someone help me?

Someone knows what I search? Is a funtcion? Is a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the page you're looking at shows how to convert a `tpl.php` to a `html.twig`. This is showing you how to update a Drupal 7 theme to be compatible with Drupal 8.

Assuming that is in fact what you're trying to do, you will normally find Drupal 7 theme templates at `sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/templates`. Once you navigate there, you should see files ending in `tpl.php`. Inside these files you *might* find a theme function being used. You can identify them as they'll look something like `function theme_YOUR_THEME_NAME_hook($variables)`.

**What is a theme function?**
A theme function is a PHP function that exists to provide HTML that is can be customized by themes and modules.

Here is [the official list of theme functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/group/themeable/7). You can find a lot more information on Drupal.org, but here are a few starter links:
1. [Theme API](https://www.drupal.org/node/722174)
2. [Using the theme layer](https://www.drupal.org/node/933976)
3. [Theme hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

I would highly recommend reading a book on theming before tackling anything else. Drupal has a lot of depth, and if you're truly on day one and already converting themes, this will serve you well. I recommend 'Using Drupal' to understand the basics of Drupal, as a lot of Drupal development can be accomplished through the User Interface. Then move onto 'Drupal 7 Development by Example Beginner's Guide' to gain an understanding of how and when you should delve into actual code development.

Comment: Thanks Paul... the realy problem is that I don´t have time to read a book or something, I was looking for videos and reading about the conversion to html.twig. 

I just get a theme and I don´t know anything about drupal =(.  Thanks a lot, this could be the begin to me =).

Comment: No problem. I understand we often don't have time to read books on subjects; however, because Drupal is so complex I promise you'll make your time up in saved project time once you've read the two I mentioned. For a quicker fix on specific subjects, you can also subscribe to Drupalize.me and buildamodule.com for excellent training videos.